# Java if a function did not get a parameter

Tags: java, function

I tried to do something like C++:

```
public void function(int x = 10) { // If user did not give an parameter, parameter= 10
    }
```

How can I set the parameter in case he did not get?

Comment: Java doesn't support that. You should use method overloading

Comment: Can you show me how? I tried before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd overload it with a method that doesn't receive a parameter, then call it with the one that you want:

```
public void function() { function(10); }
```

Your original function would then just be:

```
public void function(int x) { // ... body ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can achieve it using method overloading

```
public void function(int x) {

}

public void function() { 
    int x = 10;// If user did not give an argument, argument = 10
    function(x);
}
```